# Determine for $f(x)=x^3-x+3$ a $n \in \Bbb Z$, sucht that $f(x)=0$, for a $x\ \in [n,n+1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Determine for $f(x)=x^3-x+3$ a $n \in \Bbb Z$, sucht that $f(x)=0$, for a $x\ \in [n,n+1]$.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem for a $x\ \in [n,n+1]$. I was thinking about using the intermediate value theorem or $\lim_{x \to n+ \frac{1}{2}} f(x) =0$ but I wasn't able to solve it.

Some tips on where to start would be great!

Comment: The question is essentially asking: Find a root of the polynomial, but there is no need to be very accurate since we will ignore its fractional part and round it down to the integer $n$.

Comment: "I was thinking about using the intermediate value theorem" Then just... do... that.

Comment: @Did If I would be able to solve it with that, I wouldn't have posted the question :) Thanks for the very helpful comment though.

Comment: You are welcome. Keep up the good work (how many questions with zero personal input, already?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If $x\geq 1$ then
$$x^3-x+3=x(x^2-1)+3\geq 3.$$
On the other hand for $x\leq -3$,
$$x^3-x+3=x(x^2-1)+3\leq 8x+3\leq -21.$$
Now find what is going on in $[-3,1]$. Note that $f'(x)=3x^2-1$.